# Are there any published PbtA games where the GM rolls the dice?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse

In games "Powered by the Apocalypse" (PbtA) it's customary that the GM never rolls any dice, that all the die rolls are handled by the players.

Are there any PbtA games where the GM ever rolls for a move?  I'm looking for something that:

- has been available for sale, and
- claims itself to be either a PbtA game or to be derived from Apocalypse World (the one that started PbtA games)

Comment: As in, the GM rolls for *any* move or the GM rolls for *every* move? Or most of moves?

Comment: @kviiri, where the GM rolls for any move.

Comment: I think this is actually not a very good question for this site, as it is essentially a list question.

Comment: [List questions are not on topic for a variety of reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/4398), but it's often easy to re-ask the question in a way that takes advantage of our userbase's expertise: please tell us what problem or challenge you've encountered which you're hoping this list will solve. If the list is the best answer, you'll probably get it! But if there are other solutions, this way you can get them too.

Comment: Joe did not ask us to list *all* such material, but to provide *at least one* example if there are any. I do not think this is a list question.

Comment: @Szega As the [meta faq](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/4398) explains, "list question" does not mean each answer will be a list, but that it will accrue a list of equally-right answers which cannot benefit from Good Subjective guidelines.

Comment: @BESW Why I voted to keep open is that I think the underlying question here is: "is this an intentional design choice consistently adhered to?" (Was this your intent @Joe?) That could be answered with an example or a quote from a designer. The fact that the are multiple ways to prove something should not invalidate a question if *one* answer can be a *full proof*.

Comment: @Szega Great! When there's a post which asks that question, I'll vote to keep it open. This is not that, and we close and open based on what's there, not on its potential.

Comment: This meta may also contain usefully relevant ideas: [Can we ask about the existence of a game?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5903/4398)

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, those exist

...look no further than Apocalypse World itself, the second edition in particular.

> **V-harm as established** is the attacking car's massive minus the defending car's massive or handling, defender's choice.
>
> When you **suffer v-harm**, roll+v-harm suffered. ...

Whoever suffers V-harm, whether PC or NPC, has to make that move. This is the sole case in the core Apocalypse World moves when a roll is made for an NPC, and the rules state the MC can perform the rolling for their characters. In practice, it doesn't matter whether the roll is made by the MC or some other player, naturally.